# Highchart Annotation Connector

Tags: highcharts, annotations, react-highcharts

Is it possible to either:

A) Force An Annotation with a Shape: "Callout" to always show the connector line

B) Change text box shape conditions for a connector

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change [shape](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.shape) to connector, you can also [style](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.style) how the labels looks.

```
labelOptions: {
  shape: 'connector',
  align: 'right',
  justify: false,
  crop: true,
  style: {
    fontSize: '0.8em',
    textOutline: '1px white'
  }
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0617bh48/